# Trying to change terminal prompt using PS1

Tags: bash

I'm trying to change my terminal appearance permanently by using something like: `PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ "` but when i do it, it displays `[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $`  as my prompt can i have some help.

Comment: Your command worked just fine in my bash shell.  What shell are you using?

Comment: You are probably not using bash.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably you are using `sh` as your `shell`
to check if your shell that current running:

```
$ echo $0
```

or

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

to change your default shell to bash

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```